# How to mock Asynchronous (@Async) method in Spring Boot using Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, mockito

What is the best way to mock asynchronous (`@Async`) method with mockito? Provided service below:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class TaskService {
    @Async
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void createTask(TaskResource taskResource, UUID linkId) {
        // do some heavy task
    }
}
```

Mockito's verification as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SomeController.class)
public class SomeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean    
    private TaskService taskService;
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    // other details omitted...

    @Test
    public void shouldVerify() {
        // use mockmvc to fire to some controller which in turn call taskService.createTask
        // .... details omitted
        verify(taskService, times(1)) // taskService is mocked object
            .createTask(any(TaskResource.class), any(UUID.class));
    } 
}
```

The test method `shouldVerify` above will always throw:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> at SomeTest.java:77) // details omitted
-> at SomeTest.java:77) // details omitted 

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

The exception above won't happend if I remove `@Async` from the `TaskService.createTask` method.

Spring Boot version: [1.4.0.RELEASE](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

Mockito version: 1.10.19

Comment: Can you provide the whole implementation of your test. Does the class with method createTask is a super class?

Comment: Hi Marians27, I've edited the question. The important point is, the exception won't happen if I remove @Async annotation from the TaskService class.

Comment: Does the `@Async` annotation cause aspectj or something else to kick in? Are you sure, that the `taskService` instance you are trying to verify on is not modified by any aspects or the like?

Comment: Hi SpaceTrucker, changing the async mode to AspectJ fixed the issue. I still don't know what's the exact root cause for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out that by changing the Async mode to AspectJ fixed the issue:

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true) 
@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) // Changes here!!!
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(Main.class)
                                    .run(args);
    }
}
```

I'll accept this as a temporary hackish solution until I understand what's the real root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [bug in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6573) that we hope to fix in 1.4.1. The problem is that your mock `TaskService` is still being called asynchronously which breaks Mockito.

You could work around the problem by creating an interface for `TaskService` and creating a mock of that. As long as you leave the `@Async` annotation only on the implementation things will then work.

Something like this:

```
public interface TaskService {

    void createTask(TaskResource taskResource, UUID linkId);

}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class AsyncTaskService implements TaskService {

    @Async
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public void createTask(TaskResource taskResource, UUID linkId) {
        // do some heavy task
    }

}
```

Comment: Weird, just found today that changing async mode to AspectJ fixed my issue: `@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`. See answer below.

Comment: Use this solution if you are using JDK/CGLIB proxies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648397/spring-bean-injection-failing-due-to-proxy